trouble on making GNURADIO C++ OOT sync block
i'm trying to implement a block that process chunks of 512 bytes and return chunks of 480 bytes. At first i'm trying to work with 512 input/512 output instead to grasp the in/out mechanism of GNUradio.
Here is my work function implementation:
int cycle = 0;
int test_sync_impl::work(int noutput_items,
    gr_vector_const_void_star &input_items,
    gr_vector_void_star &output_items)
{
  auto in = static_cast<const input_type*>(input_items[0]);
  auto out = static_cast<output_type*>(output_items[0]);

  int in_index = 0;
  int out_index = 0;

  std::cout <<"input amount: " <<  nitems_read(0) << "\n";

  while(in_index + 512 <= nitems_read(0) && out_index + 512 <= noutput_items)
  {
    std::vector<uint8_t> burst(512);
    std::copy(in+in_index, in+in_index + 512, out + out_index);
    in_index += 512;
    out_index += 512;
    cycle++;
    std::cout<<"cycle: " << cycle << "\n";
  }
  consume_each(in_index);

  std::cout <<"output amount" << out_index << "\n";
  // Tell runtime system how many output items we produced.
  return out_index;
}

But currently, the block doesn't seems to work. I assume that because the while loop didn't run, that the block didn't tell scheduler how many items it processed. The problem is, i tried to parse in a data file, but the block didn't receive anything to process either
Can someone point out the flaws in this implementation ?


int test_sync_impl::work(int noutput_items,
   gr_vector_const_void_star &input_items,
   gr_vector_void_star &output_items)


This is a integer-rate block (a sync_block, an interpolator or decimator block). Yet you try to consume and produce different amounts of samples.
You chose the wrong block type for your application!
You need to use a block derived from gr::block, not gr::sync_block.
The rest of your code also looks bad

int cycle = 0;


This is a global-scope variable. Definitely wrong in this context.

  std::cout <<"input amount: " <<  nitems_read(0) << "\n";


no, nitems_read(0) is the amount of samples already consumed by previous calls to work, not the "input amount".

    std::vector<uint8_t> burst(512);


You create (and inherently destroy) this object burst every iteration, but never use it.
I'm afraid it's not clear to me what you want to do. Are you perhaps trying to re-implement the "keep M in N" block? block here?
All in all, I think you might have been skipping ahead a bit on the GNU Radio tutorials and might have directly gone for the "Creating an OOT (C++ block example)" chapter, without reading the fundamentals in detail.
